# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [System.XmlStreamWriter].writeCharacters(Date)

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, xml, quote

I am creating a xml file on click of a button. I am using `XmlStreamWriter` to generate the xml. I am fetching the data from database and then using `writeCharacters`. When I assign a date field I am getting this error.

> [System.XmlStreamWriter].writeCharacters(Date).

I want the date field to be displayed in a format of `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Below is my code:

```
Quote QuoteRecord = new Quote();

QuoteRecord = Database.query('Select QuoteNumber, ExpirationDate, Name From Quote where Id =: QId limit 1');

XmlStreamWriter w = new XmlStreamWriter();
w.writeStartElement('urn1', 'qoExpDate', 'urn1');
  w.writeCharacters(QuoteRecord.ExpirationDate);    
w.writeEndElement();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the `XmlStreamWriter` [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_xml_XmlStream_writer.htm), the signature of the `writeCharacters` method accepts `String` only.

> **writeCharacters(text)**
>    Writes the specified text to the output stream.
>
> **Signature**
>    `public Void writeCharacters(String text)`
>
> **Parameters**
>    `text`
>    Type: `String`
>
> **Return Value**
>    Type: `Void`

So instead, it should be:

```
w.writeCharacters(String.valueOf(QuoteRecord.ExpirationDate));
```

There are a few other ways to convert the date to a string, but that's the most obvious. If you want a specific format, you have to convert to `Datetime` to take advantage of its formatting methods. Casting should suffice.

```
w.writeCharacters(((Datetime)QuoteRecord.ExpirationDate).format('yyyy-MM-dd'));
```

If you need more help with formatting, consult the documentation on [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: i actually wanted in a format of YYYY-MM-DD. eg '2017-08-02'